# Sub sorting in Python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I am trying to sort a dictionary twice: by descending value, and then the keys alphabetically.

For example,

`tally = {"hello": 5, "dog": 12, "cat": 1, "bird": 5, "lion": 5}`

I want to output a list, that contains each of these words, sorted by descending value.

`output = ["dog", "hello", "bird", "lion", "cat"]`

Then within this sorting, subsort them alphabetically
As in:

`final_result = ["dog", "bird", "hello", "lion", "cat"]`

I do not actually need to get the list `output`, I only need to get `final_result`. So if there is a way to do that with 1 step, that would be better. So how do I that?

I tried using `key = lambda t:t[1]` for the initial sorting, but that resulted in a tuple with the keys and values from my dictionary. Now that obviously did not work because I wanted only the words, and also I had no idea how to do the sub sorting in that one.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: @yatu i'll edit, I forgot about that

Comment: @yatu My answer is just a cleaner version of your logic. Why did your delete the answer? I'll add credits if you are fine with it. Because you are the brain behind the logic.

Comment: @yatu Yeah. I added the credits though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom `key` to sort according to both conditions. This can be done in a single step by specifying a tuple `(-value,key)`, where by taking the negative sign of the `values` we get a descending sort:

```
>>> sorted(tally,key=lambda x: (-tally[x],x))
['dog', 'bird', 'hello', 'lion', 'cat']
```

The logic `(-value,key)` is given by [**`@yatu`**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9698684/yatu)

Comment: Thanks for the 2 of you, not sure why yatu deleted their answer, but anyway I am still confused. This code worked, but i don't know why and how it does so... I am new to Python so I didn't really understand the logic...